# How to enable virtualisation in Windows 10?

Tags: android, windows-10, virtualization, haxm

I am trying to install intel-HAXM for my Android application, but it shows this error:"This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed". I have tried many methods to turn on virtualization in BIOS but my system doesn't seem to have that option. I am using Windows 10 Home, with AMD A6 processor. Does my system support virtualization?

[image]

Comment: You have an **AMD** processor and are trying to run **Intel** product?

Answer (score 1):

You have an AMD. HAXM is for intel processors. You can't "enable" it.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor may not support that technology, even if it's Intel. To check that out download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) programm and check your processor instructions in the `CPU` section, like at the picture attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an AMD processor so it won't work. Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) for the best speed. It worked a lot faster for me than the native emulator.